# how to position background image in futter

Tags: flutter, background-image

[image]

I want to achieve desired UI as shown in above Screen shot, in it there is a gradient background color which is no problem but there are background pics like cresent, I have cresent pic in png but i can't figure how to display it at bottom left, this has to be a background image as there will be text that might be over it.

Comment: try to use `center` on RadialGradient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is your Card with Gradiant and your Background Image Alignment in bottomLeft don't forget to change asset**

```
             Container(
                height: 200,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: 
                  BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  image: const DecorationImage(
                      alignment: 
                      Alignment.bottomLeft,
                      image: 
                     AssetImage(AppAssets.logo)),
                  gradient: RadialGradient(
                    center: 
                    Alignment.bottomRight,
                    radius: 1.5,
                    colors: [
                      Colors.pink.withAlpha(100),
                      Colors.pink.withAlpha(200),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can play with `RadialGradient` parameters

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Center(
    child: Container(
      height: 200,
      width: 400,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: RadialGradient(
          center: Alignment.bottomRight,
          radius: 1.5,
          colors: [
            Colors.pink.withAlpha(100),
            Colors.pink.withAlpha(200),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

[image]